# Correct Usage of Verb forms

Tags: verbs

i am confused between these two , which one is more accurate -
1). I saw him smiling . 
2) . I saw him smile.

Comment: Did he smile briefly, or continue smiling for a while?

Comment: Does it depend on the time duration he smiled for

Comment: I would interpret it as (1) When I saw him he was already smiling. (2) I was looking at him when his expression changed to a smile.

Comment: If an obj is added like - 1) I saw him smiling at his friend 2) i saw him smile at his friend , Would the implications still be the same

Comment: Neither is more accurate than the other without more context. As standalone sentences, they are equally valid and understandable.